# How to retrieve arguments from a "fluid" decorated function

Tags: python, python-decorators

Suppose I have this decorator:

```
def decorator(f):
  def f_wrap(*args):
    for item in args:
      print(args)
    return f(*args)
  return f_wrap
```

When used as "permanent" decorators with the `@` syntax, `args` retrieves the arguments of the wrapped function. For example, when used with the class below, I receive the instance of `MyObject`.

```
Class MyObject(object):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  @decorator
  def function(self):
    return
```

How can I achieve the same result using a "fluid" decorator. Or a decorator that is not permanently bound to the function it is decorating? For example:

```
def decorator(f):
    def f_wrap(*args):
        if (not args):
            print("Nothing in args")
        return f(*args)
    return f_wrap

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def function(self):
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myobj = MyClass()
    myobj.function = decorator(myobj.function)
    myobj.function()
```

In this case, the `args` tuple always returns empty (I always get "Nothing in args"), even though I anticipated that it would return the instance variable `myobj`.

**EDIT**:

In case it was not clear from [@AChampion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2750492/achampion)'s post the solution is to simply call the fluid-decoratored method as an "unbound" method. E.g.,

```
from types import MethodType
def decorator(f):
    def f_wrap(*args):
        # I replaced this with an iteration through
        #   args. It's a bit more demonstrative.
        for item in args:
            print(item)
        return f(*args)
    return f_wrap

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def function(self):
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myobj = MyClass()
    myobj.function = MethodType(decorator(MyClass.function), myobj)
    myobj.function()
```

Comment: Are you sure you condition is correct `all(args)` would return False with any non-falsifiable argument, e.g. 0. Did you just want the `len` of args? The reason for the difference is in the second instance you have a `bound` function (print out `f`) and the first you just have passed in an unbound function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the difference is that you are wrapping different things, a unbound method vs a bound method:

```
class MyObject(object):
    @decorator
    def function(self):
         pass
```

Is equivalent to:

```
import types
class MyClass(object):
    def function(self):
        pass

m = MyClass(object)
m.function = types.MethodType(decorator(MyClass.function), m)
```

Not:

```
m.function = decorator(m.function)
```

The first being an unbound method, the second being a bound method.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using `all` properly. `all` returns a bool on whether all conditions are met inside what you are checking for in `all`. In your case, you aren't really doing anything. You will always evaluate to True with how you are using `all`.

I believe what you are looking for is simply this:

```
if not args:
```

Now, ultimately what this checks is if the method you are executing has *args. For the case of the function you have, you aren't passing any arguments, therefore, with the `if not args` check, you will actually get:

```
"Nothing in args"
```

However, if you add an argument to your method as such:

```
def function(self, x):
    return
```

Then call: `myobj.function(1)`

You will *not* get "Nothing in args".

To answer your last question about not getting your instance. If you print out `f` using this method of calling your decorator:

```
myobj.function = decorator(myobj.function)
myobj.function()
```

You will get a bound method:

```
<bound method MyClass.function of <__main__.MyClass object at 0x102002390>>
```

Now, set up your decorator as such:

```
@decorator
def function(self):
    return
```

You will see you get a function attached to your class object:

```
<function MyClass.function at 0x102001620>
```

Hence showing that they aren't doing the exact same thing you would expect. Hope this helps clarify a bit.

Comment: The question remains though: why don't I get the instance variable? Using a "permanent" decorator, I get the instance even though no arguments are passed. E.g., the program returns: `<__main__.MyClass object at [address]>`.

Comment: @franklin Updated. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: The difference is between wrapping a bound method vs an unbound method

Comment: @idjaw That's exactly correct. However, it still uses the permanent decorator that I was trying to avoid. It is definitely an issue involving bound & unbound methods (which I admittedly need to read up about). Thank you!